# Adding two row counts in stored procedure in DB2 with parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, db2, resultset

I am trying to create a stored procedure that uses select to get the amount of rows in two tables and then prints out the result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN tab1 varchar(20), IN tab2 varchar(20), out msg INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN


DECLARE r1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1;

DECLARE r2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab2;

OPEN r1;

OPEN r2;

---- somehow add the 2 together -----

CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'Zeilen = ' );
CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( msg );

END @
```

I updated the whole source code adding cursors since a select (variable)= something doesn't seem to work like

```
 SELECT tableOneCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1);
```

But now the problem is that creating the procedure I get the error that tab1 is unknown which is obvious since it is a variable and I don't know how to add the 2 cursors.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

TheVagabond

Comment: `SELECT` is not the way to assign variable values the way you're trying to do that, not in DB2 anyway. Also, you can't use variables as object names -- google for "dynamic SQL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mustaccio said, you should use variables

```
DECLARE QTY INTEGER;
SET QTY = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1);
```